# Swift: How to terminate a function outside the execution of the function

Tags: swift, function, cocoa-touch

I'm fairly new to Swift still.  I'm wondering how I can terminate an animation function in swift outside the execution of the function.  In the case below I run an animation for 15 seconds but anytime a user presses a certain button I want the animation to stop and the elements to disappear.  Any thoughts on the best way to go about this?  Here is the function.

```
func createTimerAnimation () {
    // create timer line shapes

    guard self.timerisActive else {

        print("in guard 1")
        return
    }

    let screenWidth = (self.view.bounds.width)
    let screenHeight = (self.view.bounds.height)

    let timerShapeLeft = drawTimerShape()
    let timerShapeRight = drawTimerShape()
    let timerShapeCenter = drawTimerShape()

    view.addSubview(timerShapeLeft)
    view.addSubview(timerShapeRight)
    view.addSubview(timerShapeCenter)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 14.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations:{
            timerShapeLeft.frame = CGRect (x: (screenWidth / 2), y: (screenHeight - 60), width: timerShapeLeft.frame.width, height: (timerShapeLeft.frame.height - 30))
            timerShapeRight.frame = CGRect (x: (screenWidth / 2), y: (screenHeight - 60), width: timerShapeRight.frame.width, height: (timerShapeRight.frame.height - 30))
            timerShapeCenter.frame = CGRect (x: (screenWidth / 2), y: (screenHeight - 60), width: timerShapeCenter.frame.width, height: (timerShapeCenter.frame.height))
            timerShapeLeft.alpha = 1.0
            timerShapeRight.alpha = 1.0
            timerShapeCenter.alpha = 0.4
            timerShapeLeft.tintColor = self.hexGray
            timerShapeRight.tintColor = self.hexGray

            guard self.timerisActive else {

                print("in guard 1")
                return
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animations are actually handled by the view's layer so you can cancel them there with [CALayer.removeAllAnimations()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410810-removeallanimations) :

```
view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```